# Alternative to Window.Print()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a print button so that when it is pressed, it prints the whole webpage. I am currently using Window.print() of javascript. But I ran into error; when ever i press the print button more than once, the link stops working. What is the problem with it ? Is there an alternative to this in jquery or any other ? I am using grails 1.3.7.
Thanks

Comment: whatever the problem with it is, it isn't that you are using `window.print()` (which is the only way to get the browser to print something without using its native UI).

Comment: my wild guess is that you are using chrome and it blocks window.print() if pressed too many times. Check out your javascript console to see if it spits an error or warning.

Comment: Yes i was using chrome, and after your comment I checked it in firefox, it is working fine there. Is there any way in chrome to make this work ?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way to `window.print()` is

```
document.execCommand('print');
```